# waiting for inner observables in rxjs

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a function that I want to return after 3 obersverables have complete:

```
initialize(){
  let src1:Observable<Account>; //initialization omitted for brevity
  let src2: Observable<User>;   //initialization omitted for brevity

  // this is one is the problem
  let src3: Observable<Company[]> = this.myHttpService.getCompanies()
                                                  .pipe(
                                                     //do something that calls `this.myHttpService.getDepartments(company.id)` for each company one at a time.
                                                   );

  return merge(src1, src2, src3);                        

}
```

For `src3`, each company has multiple departments.  I would like to make a call to `this.myHttpService.getDepartments(company.id)` for each company.  Only once all `this.myHttpService.getDepartments` has been called for each company.  Only then should `src3` be complete.

Ive gone through any number of combination of `concatMap`, `mergeMap`....and I am just not getting it.

How do I take each company, get their departments (a `Department[]`) one company at a time, and then once that is done, `src3` is complete?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Observable.forkJoin to achieve this.

```
return forkJoin([src1,src2,src3]).map(result=>{
   //output as result[0], result[1], result[2]
});
```

Comment: but for `src3`, how do I get all the departments for each company?  What rxjs operators would I use?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try something along these lines.

```
initialize(){
  let src1:Observable<Account>; //initialization omitted for brevity
  let src2: Observable<User>;   //initialization omitted for brevity

  // this is one is the problem
  let src3: Observable<Company[]> = this.myHttpService.getCompanies().pipe(
     map(companies: Array<any> => companies.map(
       company => this.myHttpService.getDepartments(company.id)
     )),
     switchMap(getDepObsArray: Array<Observable<any>> => forkJoin(getDepObsArray))
  );

  return forkJoin(src1, src2, src3);                        

}
```

The idea is to use `forkJoin` to ensure that

- `src3` returns only once all calls to the service have completed
- `initialize` returns an Observable which emits only when `src1` `src2` and `src3` complete

Answer (score 0):

There are many Ways to achieve your goal. You could use concatAll, mergeMap and toArray:

concatAll unpacks an array into individual objects, mergeMap transformes these objects into an observable emitting company's departments and toArray collects the output of the mergeMap function to ensure all departments are retrieved before the observable completes

final code could look like this:

```js
    let src3: Observable<{company: Company, departments: Department[]}[]> = this.myHttpService.getCompanies()
        .pipe(
            concatAll(), // use this if your getCompanies() function returns Observable<Company[]> to get a single company
            mergeMap(company => this.myHttpService.getDepartments(company.id).pipe(
                map(departments => ({ company, departments })))
            ),
            toArray(), // here you receive {company: Company, departments: Department[]}[]
        );
```